# How secure is using .htpasswd to secure a directory?

Tags: htaccess, directory, htpasswd

I'm basically creating something off of my main domain `www.mywebsite.com/intranet`.
I've created *.htpasswd* protection for that `intranet` directory.

I can't implement individual user passwords yet and I want to use *.htpasswd* as an interim solution.

How secure is this method?

What steps should I take to make this more secure?  What permissions for *.htaccess* and *.htpasswd*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the disadvantages of basic authentication according to [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Disadvantages):

> Although the scheme is easily
>   implemented, it relies on the
>   assumption that the connection between
>   the client and server computers is
>   secure and can be trusted.
>   Specifically, if SSL/TLS is not used,
>   then the credentials are passed as
>   plaintext and could be intercepted.
>
> Existing browsers retain
>   authentication information until the
>   tab or browser is closed or the user
>   clears the history. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Disadvantages) HTTP does not
>   provide a method for a server to
>   direct clients to discard these cached
>   credentials. This means that there is
>   no effective way for a server to "log
>   out" the user without closing the
>   browser. This is a significant defect
>   that requires browser manufacturers to
>   support a 'logout' user interface
>   element or API available to
>   JavaScript, further extensions to
>   HTTP, or use of existing alternative
>   techniques such as retrieving the page
>   over SSL/TLS with an unguessable
>   string in the URL.

As the word "basic" in its name implies it offers very basic protection but not much more then that. If you're going to using it as a stop gap measure until you can get a custom authentication scheme in place then it's definitely better then nothing. But if your goal is "real" security then you should be implementing a custom authentication system ASAP.

Comment: Whilst I agree with this, you could use digest authentication which is more secure.

Comment: John, I have many folders with pictures that have watermarks. I would like to have the original images in .PSD in a sub-folder as backup. I don't want anybody to be able to get to them obviously, and I also don't want SEs to crawl those folders. Is the .htpasswd method enough for me? Furthermore, do I need to exclude such sub-directories in robots.txt?